# Setting a Layout to bottom of ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview, tablelayout

So I have a `TableLayout` that I want to put inside a ScrollView. But I have a problem:

The TableLayout is initially empty and I programmatically add `TableRows` to it by tapping a button. This works fine if I put the `TableLayout` into the `ScrollView` normally (ie: when I scroll, it works perfectly).

But I want to make it so that the TableLayout is at the BOTTOM of the `ScrollView`. So every time I add a `TableRow`, the last cell will always be aligned to the bottom of the parent ScrollView. (kind of like how mobile chats work - when you press send, your message is put at the bottom while all the other messages are pushed up).

What happens is that if I use `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to try to achieve this, I'm unable to scroll upwards, so I'm unable to see any of the rows that are pushed upwards out of the view of the screen. However, I'm able to scroll downwards for some reason (into emptiness), which shouldn't be possible since the last `TableRow` should be at the bottom.

This is the relevant XML code (the LinearLayout may be redundant/not required):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"    
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- 2 Buttons here -->
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
   <!-- attributes of textView> -->/>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/tableScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/stripes_background" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">    

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/outputTable"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:divider="@drawable/table_divider" 
            android:showDividers="middle">    
    </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>

<Button
    <!-- Button attributes --> />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Divider:
[image: Divider]
Background:
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsJmp.jpg)

Comment: You can use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and then use "alignparent_bottom" attribute. I hope , this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- 2 Buttons here -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="uiop turn" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/tableScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/botton_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/outputTable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:showDividers="middle" >

            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botton_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="roll" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When I tried this, I get an error for: `android:layout_alignParentBottom` which says `error: Error: Boolean types not allowed (at 'layout_alignBottom' with value 'true').`

Comment: its not "layout_alignBottom", it is "layout_alignParentBottom".

Comment: Ohh okay sorry. I changed it and there's no error now. But I still have the same outcome: I can scroll downwards but I can't scroll up... and there's nothing downwards.

Comment: Updated my post with all of it

Comment: @Trust add your drawables and rest components if it fits you.

Comment: Sure okay, i'll attach them. But what do they have to do with the problem though? Even if I had no drawables the problem would remain the same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45009/discussion-between-amit-singh-and-trust)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked. It is code for `Button` that will scroll to the bottom as soon as I add new `TableRow`to the TableLayout `tblLayout`.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TableRow tbr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                TextView tv= new TextView(getBaseContext());
                tv.setTextSize(80f);
                tv.setText("Item" + a++);
                tbr.addView(tv);
                tblLayout.addView(tbr);
                mScroll.post(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() { 
                         mScroll.scrollTo(0, mScroll.getBottom());
                    } 
            });
            }
        });
```

It should work wherever the Button is placed. Either inside or outside. Variable a is `int` declared at the top. Please tell me if you didn't get anything and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fix my problem. My problem has to do with the entire UI created, not if it can scroll to the bottom. I'll post a screenshot in a second to clarify

Comment: It's really difficult to say what do you want I ran my code and I think it works as you want. I think I can solve your problem. So you can send me code if you want